# Memory warning in table view image application - Lazy downloading

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, lazy-loading

I am downloading images using lazy table downloading and saving images in document folder. The  images are displayed in a table view.

Table view has 36 images in one page, and approximately 10 pages.

I'm getting memory warnings again and again.

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem ?
Because I already remove all objects, but problem isn't solved yet.

Comment: You'll have to post some relevant code otherwise we'd just be guessing.

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not make sure that you are releasing all of the images when they are scrolled off the screen. Otherwise you will get memory issues. Ensure you have implemented -(void)dealloc in all your custom views and are releasing anything that you retain!!

Comment: Have you tried to cache images?

Comment: You **don't** want to be caching images if you're having memory problems, which includes not using `[UIImage imageNamed:filename]`.  If you want more help, you need to show us code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has memory leak, you can check it by using profile(cmd + i),
or You can try it like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIndentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_3_0
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
#else
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
#endif
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    } else {
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:999] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    //imageView
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"filePath"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.tag = 999;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    return cell;
}
```